# How to install android apps for pc

Tags: android, whatsapp

I have tired installing android apps for pc but isn't working fine. can someone help me. I  have downloaded apk and tried installing on windows xp but i am not able to open the that file which i have downloaded.

Comment: check my answer and download bluestack and enjoy any app in your pc.accept my answer if it is helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic question you have asked you need to download bluestack in order to run any android app.  here is the brief ultimate guide to install android apps on pc. Install bluestack and search your apps from there and install it.

Source : http://www.findandroidappsforpc.com/ultimate-guide-to-download-android-apps-for-pc/

Comment: Thanks for your awesome tutorial i just installed successfully

Answer (score 0):

download bluestack http://www.bluestacks.com/ for your xp version and install app and enjoy it.
http://en.softonic.com/s/android-app-installer/windows-xp